# How to get total of numbers in an array from SharePoint list items

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I'm creating a spfx web part using Reactjs. I have a function getting an array of items from a SharePoint list that includes a number column of "Hours".  I need to get a total for all the hours that have been returned but can't figure out how to calculate that.

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I've run through all kinds of loops and for some reason I can't get it to work.  I've verified that I am getting data from the Hours column.

I'll also state the obligatory "I'm new to spfx and react".  :)  TIA for any help!

```
private readItem(): void {
  this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Time Off')/items?$select=Title,Id,Hours`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'odata-version': ''
      }
    }).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<ITimeOffItem[]> => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((item: ITimeOffItem[]): void => {

      console.log(item); //the data is here including Hours

      this.setState({
        items: item,
        hoursTotal: //????How do I get the sum of "Hours" and assign it to a number in state
      });

    });
}
```

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(item);`?

Comment: Here's the output
{value: Array(8)}
value: Array(8)
0:
Hours: 4
ID: 24
Id: 24
Title: "Work from Home"
__proto__: Object
1: {Id: 25, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 6, ID: 25}
2: {Id: 26, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 5, ID: 26}
3: {Id: 27, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 3, ID: 27}
4: {Id: 28, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 7, ID: 28}
5: {Id: 29, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 8, ID: 29}
6: {Id: 30, Title: "Holiday", Hours: 8, ID: 30}
7: {Id: 31, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 32, ID: 31}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: Sorry - the copy paste doesn't look like it expanded everything... I expanded a few others so hopefully this is more helpful:  
{value: Array(8)}
value: Array(8)
0:
Hours: 4
ID: 24
Id: 24
Title: "Work from Home"
__proto__: Object
1:
Hours: 6
ID: 25
Id: 25
Title: "Comp Time"
__proto__: Object
2:
Hours: 5
ID: 26
Id: 26
Title: "Comp Time"
__proto__: Object
/////skipping some for space////
7:
Hours: 32
ID: 31
Id: 31
Title: "Work from Home"
__proto__: Object
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to loop through the items and add the hours

```js
function countHours(items) {
  if (!items) {
    return 0;
  }

  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    total += items[i].Hours;
  }

  return total;
}

const item = [
  { Id: 25, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 6, ID: 25 },
  { Id: 26, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 5, ID: 26 },
  { Id: 27, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 3, ID: 27 },
  { Id: 28, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 7, ID: 28 },
  { Id: 29, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 8, ID: 29 },
  { Id: 30, Title: "Holiday", Hours: 8, ID: 30 },
  { Id: 31, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 32, ID: 31 }
];

console.log(countHours(item));
```

Use it like

```
this.setState({
    items: item,
    hoursTotal: countHours(item)
});
```

you can also use reduce

```js
const item = [
  { Id: 25, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 6, ID: 25 },
  { Id: 26, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 5, ID: 26 },
  { Id: 27, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 3, ID: 27 },
  { Id: 28, Title: "Comp Time", Hours: 7, ID: 28 },
  { Id: 29, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 8, ID: 29 },
  { Id: 30, Title: "Holiday", Hours: 8, ID: 30 },
  { Id: 31, Title: "Work from Home", Hours: 32, ID: 31 }
];
const sum = item.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b.Hours; }, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer this without knowing what the data structure looks like, but if you are trying to sum an array of numbers you could use `reduce`.

```
const hours = [7, 5, 3, 1, 7]

const totalHours = hours.reduce((accumulator, hour) => accumulator + hour)
```

Comment: Hi Nitsew... I think I tried that at some point but the array has more than just straight numbers in it and I couldn't figure out that syntax... sorry I didn't include that to start.  

Here's an example of what's coming back if that helps:
1:
Hours: 6
ID: 25
Id: 25
Title: "Comp Time"
__proto__: Object
2:
Hours: 5
ID: 26
Id: 26
Title: "Comp Time"
__proto__: Object